# Google Maps API v2 infoWindow tail/pointer size

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I need to reduce the size of the default infoWindow tail to be 10px and centered to the map location i.e. the tail should be centered to the infoWindow and not one of the sides.

Is this possible and if so have you got any examples please?

Thanks in advance,

B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a custom infoWindow for that, have a look at
[this example](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infowindow_custom/infowindow-custom.html).

View Source in Google Chrome / Firefox - `CTRL+U`

You could also try to edit/use InfoBox from [these libraries](http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries#InfoBox).

I don't think you can do what you want with just CSS since google uses images for the markers. Maybe a combination of CSS overrides and custom image(s) would do, but prepare to dig into a lot of messy (optimized) css/html.